# p:selectManyCheckbox : getting the selected value into bean

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, web, primefaces

I want to assign a List of users to a project then my xhtml is like this:

```
            <p:dataTable id="dta" value="#{UtilisateurComponent.listUtilisateurs()}"  var="current" rows="15" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom">
                <p:column>
                    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="selectUser" value="#{ProjetComponent.projet.utilisateurs}"   >
                        <f:selectItem  var="utilisateurs" value="#{utilisateurs.iduser}" itemLabel=""/>
                        <f:converter converterId="entityConverter" />
                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton image="save" ajax="false" style="margin-right:20px;" value="#{projetmsgs['navigation.save']}" action="#{ProjetComponent.saveProjetUtilisateurs1(ProjetComponent.projet,ProjetComponent.projet.utilisateurs)}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
</p:panel>
```

and this is the method save in the ProjetComponent:

```
private Projet projet;
    private Utilisateur utilisateurs;
    @Autowired
    private ProjetDAO projetDAO;
    @Autowired
    private UtilisateurDAO utilisateurDAO;
    @Autowired
    private ProjetService projetService;
    @Transactional
    public String saveProjetUtilisateurs1(Projet p, List<Utilisateur> utilisateur) {
        projet = projetService.saveProjetUtilisateurs(p, utilisateur);
        return "/jsf/projet/viewProjet.xhtml";
    }
```

and this the method save in the ProjetService class called by the component ProjetCompnent:

```
@Transactional
public Projet saveProjetUtilisateurs(Projet projet,List<Utilisateur> ut)
{

    projet.setAvancement(projet.getAvancement());
    projet.setConfidentialite(projet.getConfidentialite());
    projet.setDatedebut(projet.getDatedebut());
    projet.setDatefineffective(projet.getDatefineffective());
    projet.setDatefinprevu(projet.getDatefinprevu());
    projet.setDescription(projet.getDescription());
    projet.setDurreprojet(projet.getDurreprojet());
    projet.setNomprojet(projet.getNomprojet());
    projet.setObjectifprojet(projet.getObjectifprojet());
    projet.setStatut(projet.getStatut());
    projet.setUtilisateurs(ut);

    projet = projetDAO.store(projet);
    projetDAO.flush();
    return projet;
}
```

and this is the Projet Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Projet implements Serializable {
        @Id
        private Integer idprojet;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projets", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    java.util.List<com.gestion.projet.domain.Utilisateur> utilisateurs;
    }
```

screentshot: 
[image]

and the problem is getting an empty list of users:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `p:ajax` on `h:selectManyCheckbox`.

```
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />
```

If you want the Checkbox based multiple selection on Primeface Datatable, no need to use the explicit `h:selectManyCheckbox`.

You could do that by specifying `selectionMode="multiple"` attribute on first/last `p:column`.

See the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).

Comment: i have the same problem with selectionMode="multiple"

Comment: Then use `p:ajax` on `p:dataTable` itself. `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" />`. If its still a problem then there might be a problem in your `entityConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

this is the entityConverter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "entityConverter")
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

    private static Map<Object, String> entities = new WeakHashMap<Object, String>();


    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
        synchronized (entities) {
            if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                entities.put(entity, uuid);
                return uuid;
            } else {
                return entities.get(entity);
            }
        }
    }


    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
        for (Entry<Object, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```